# What is a good word for a person who doesn't masturbate?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, offensive-language

Is there a word for a person who doesn't masturbate? If so, what would he/she/it be known as?

Comment: Why "he"? And I guess when there is nobody in this category, we don't need words to describe them!

Comment: okay, my mistake. An error well identified. Its [he/she/it] now.

Comment: I'm going with "non-existent".

Comment: Would not s/he be known by her/his name?

Comment: [Aphephobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_being_touched)?

Comment: There isn't one, so I am going to go for *nonanist*.

Comment: If you take "he" as the pronoun of choice, the word you want is "liar".

Comment: Prudish? It's not very specific, but it does imply disapproval and/or dislike of amoral acts, if only in principle.

Comment: Who doesn't _like_ to, or who doesn't? There's a difference.

Comment: *fictitious* or *paralysed*

Comment: Sheldon Cooper.

Comment: The title and the question don't agree. Somebody who dissaproves of the act isn't necessarily somebody who doesn't do it themselves.

Comment: I call them a **Mt. Fuji**. They can burst at any time.

Comment: They are a **nofapper** (vulgar!), named after the reddit community **r/NoFap**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Aonanist*. An *onanist* being a man who masturbates or practices coitus interruptus, an *aonanist* would be someone who doesn't (similar to *social/asocial*).

I don't think *onanophobe* is right because that would indicate a fear of onanism while there are certainly other reasons for not practicing it.

Answer (score 7):

You could call such a person an [onanophobe](http://books.google.com/books?id=RGdbZA0Vaz0C&pg=PA102&dq=onanophobia&hl=en&ei=j9HFTfinIOTV0QG18JyBCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=onanophobia&f=false).

Comment: this answer is so far the most satisfactory one to the question.

Comment: nonanist perhaps?

Comment: Someone downvoted this, it would help to know why.

Answer (score 4):

asexual --> an-onanist?

Which is to say, I do not know either, but other people are attempting to coin a word that is the opposite of an *onanist*--`a man guilty of the sin of onanism, or spilling his seed`.  This is an allusion to Onan, in Genesis 38:

> Gen 38:8-10 *(NRSV)*
>
> Then Judah said to Onan, ‘Go in to your brother’s wife and perform the duty of a brother-in-law to her; raise up offspring for your brother.’ But since Onan knew that the offspring would not be his, he spilled his semen on the ground whenever he went in to his brother’s wife, so that he would not give offspring to his brother. What he did was displeasing in the sight of the Lord, and he put him to death also.

While Ronald's aversion to *onanophobe* is well reasoned, it does have the benefit of a literary reference.

Comment: This is often taken as referring to coitus interruptus, so not necessarily relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I have nothing to offer that refers specifically to masturbation, but you probably could accommodate (though you don't mention the context for your need) by using the adjective **continent**, which means “exercising self-restraint, especially sexually”.

Comment: that person doesn't like it, nothing about avoiding it or something like that.

Comment: **continent** is close to **chaste** but i'm still open for more words. P.S: its not about controlling or abstaining, its about hating, disliking the act.

Comment: Consider also *asexual*.

Comment: @Cerberus: Wouldn't that exclude someone who has sexual relations with someone else but doesn't masturbate?  Similarly for anything along the lines of "exercising sexual self-restraint", such as continent or chaste.

Comment: @FredNurk: Yeah, that was merely a suggestion, not a real solution to this question, which I rather think there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't a word, but often a phrase used is "a person who refrains from self-abuse."  That phrase is very clear but also very clearly judgmental.

Answer (score 0):

*Some* people who don't masturbate are [anhedonic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anhedonic).

> ANHEDONIA
>   :  a psychological condition characterized by inability to experience pleasure in normally pleasurable acts
>   — an·he·don·ic adjective

[Sexual anhedonia, or pleasure dissociative orgasmic disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_anhedonia) is a real thing:

> a condition in which an individual cannot feel pleasure from an orgasm. It is thought to be a variant of hypoactive sexual desire disorder.

Answer (score 0):

What could be better for such a person than *spank-blanker?*

Nothing, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Or they could be a *celibater...*

Answer (score -1):

Celibacy is sexual abstinence. So, a "celibate" is one who don't masturbate.

Comment: Well, that may not be true depending on your definition of sexual abstinence.